# Eclipse and GWT looking for inherited module in wrong package, despite gwt.xml file having correct path?

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, gwt, package

Upon attempting to run my Google Web Application I've been working on in Eclipse using GWT, it gives me this error:

"Loading modules
   com.example.pbot.Pbot
      Loading inherited module 'com.example.pbot.Pbot'
         [ERROR] Unable to find 'com/example/pbot/Pbot.gwt.xml' on your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath entry for source?
[ERROR] shell failed in doStartup method"

All of my packages are com.pbot, com.pbot.client, com.pbot.server, etc; I don't know where it's seeing com.example.

The entry-point class in the gwt.xml file is com.pbot.client.Pbot, which is my entry point class. Here's the full gwt.xml:

```
-->
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 2.5.1//EN"
  "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/tags/2.5.1/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">
<module rename-to='pbot'>
  <!-- Inherit the core Web Toolkit stuff.                        -->
  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>

  <!-- Inherit the default GWT style sheet.  You can change       -->
  <!-- the theme of your GWT application by uncommenting          -->
  <!-- any one of the following lines.                            -->
  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.clean.Clean'/>
  <!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard'/> -->
  <!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.chrome.Chrome'/> -->
  <!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.dark.Dark'/>     -->

  <!-- Other module inherits                                      -->

  <!-- Specify the app entry point class.                         -->
    <entry-point class='com.pbot.client.Pbot'/>
  <!-- Specify the paths for translatable code                    -->
  <source path='client'/>
  <source path='shared'/>

</module>
```

I've cleaned, refreshed and restarted the project, I don't know what else to do.  Where is it reading "com.example?"  Please help!

Comment: check you web.xml(WAR/web-inf ) ; sometimes this error came from this file if you are using some server code.

Answer (score 6):

Check the run configurations -> Arguments. There will be a reference of `com.example.pbot.Pbot`.

I think, this is what Thomas mentioned.

[image]

Comment: That's exactly where the rogue "com.example.pbot.Pbot" was, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Check the project properties, in the GWT page, it probably references the `com.example` that you initially created.

Comment: I don't see it in the Pbot.gwt.xml (in com.pbot).  Anywhere else I can look?

Comment: See [here](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/running_and_debugging_2_0), [there](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/gwt_compile) and in _Google → Web Toolkit Settings_ from the project context-menu (or _Google → Web Toolkit_ in the project properties)